# Acumatica Add Delivery Week to Sales Order Screen

Tags: acumatica, week-number

I try to had Delivery Week in Sales Order Screen.
I've taken roughly the sames attributes as in the screen Weekly Crew Time Entry (EP307100) but I have an error when saving the form : Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar. The statement has been terminated.

[image: Delivery Week Sales Order Screen]

[image: User Defined Field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message comes from the SQL server. It looks like your field is `nvarchar` in the database and not `integer`.